# Replace text within a text file with Windows command line

Tags: command-line

Without being able to install all sorts of fancy find and replace tools, I need to find and replace strings within text files with the command line from Windows Server 2008.

How would I do that?

Example:

```
text.md

    Hello world!
```

Change to:

```
text.md

    Hello everyone!
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
for /f %%A in (text.md) do (

    set "line=%%A"

    if defined line (

        // and here the replacement

    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

Comment: Plain batch replacement has restrictions and it is useful to know exactly what text we are dealing with - or we could be wasting our time because it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type text.md|find /n /v """') do (

    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:world=everyone%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.

)) >text2.md

move /Y text2.md text.md
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `repl.bat` which you would put on the path (say in C:\Windows or a utility folder that you add to the path)

```
type "text.md"|repl "world" "everyone" >"text.tmp"
move /y "text.tmp" "text.md"
```

`repl.bat` is a SED-like helper batch file from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

`findrepl.bat` is GREP-like helper batch file from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

If you want plain batch techniques then it will depend on the exact task and text makeup.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this goes beyond my understanding. :)

Comment: I see. I would need to put `repl.bat` in the path which I'm afraid I can't do within the environment I'm working with. Thanks for the clear explanation though!

Comment: It's most widely useful on the path, but you can also put it in the current directory with your text file and it will work too.

Comment: I still am bound tot the fact I cannot do that. :(

Comment: You cannot do what?  To use repl you copy and paste into notepad, save it as a bat file in the same folder as your text file, and it will work.  What further restrictions do you have?

Comment: That. I cannot put a bat in the same folder as the text file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the replacement string has a double quote.